# 4-way wiring mess

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

So I'm trying to fix this box because I believe it is where my problem is but it's making my eyes cross. The switch on the right goes to the front porch light and the 3-way on the left I believe to be the first switch in my three switch setup. Currently when I turn off the this 3-way (switch 1) or the 4-way (middle switch) the other 3-way (switch 3) doesn't work. What is going on in this box and how can I fix it?[image: box from hell]
[image: close up]

Answer (score 1):

The black screw has a black wire twisted in common with other blacks, so that's most likely always-hot supply.  And the neutrals are all tied together, which also shows power is fed from this end - the traveling white wire is true neutral.

There are two brass screws going to black and red in the same sheath, so clearly those are your travelers.

That means that either red or black will be energized at all times, and that should change when you throw the switch obviously.  One wire should measure solid 120V to neutral, and the other somewhat less than 120V (but more than zero owing to capacitive coupling).  *Neutral is not ground, but just for a momentary test, you could "borrow" it since it's bare.*

If that all passes, move to the next switch position, and do the same test of messengers.  A 4-way has a pair of messengers in and out, so test each pair.  If a switch fails the test, bad switch.  If the upstream switch passes but the inputs of the downstream switch fail, bad cable between.

While you're in there, see all those backstabs?  They are notorious for failure, especially from the side-force of cramming a switch back into a box. I'd move the connections to screw terminals *one wire at a time* so you don't get em mixed up. Fair chance your problem is a hokey backstab connection.

Comment: When light is on the copper screw/ black wire is 124.5v and the copper screw/red wire is 110v. When light is off copper screw/ black wire is 2v and the copper screw/red wire is 124.6v. Black screw constant 124.5v. I also moved to using screws instead of back stabs. Still same issue. Moving to next switch.

Comment: I discovered my problem to be because I am using a Lutron MSCL-OP153M on my load side. I have corrected my two 3-way switches and now they function properly. Now to figure out how to wire the manual switch 4-way.